# Win 10 Memory leak?

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory

I think I have a problem with my PC, but I can't figure out the origin of the problem, paged-pool grows till my PC uses 11Gb of RAM, but only 2Gb is used by the user.

- Trough RamMap I see this:

[image: RamMap screen]

Both Mapped File and Paged Pool seem to big;

- From PoolMon I get this:

[image: Poolmon screen]

From PoolMon the problem seems to be MmSt, but, as far as I know MmSt is a Windows Memory manager, so I'm stuck here.

- Task Manager:

  - Performance:

[image: Performance]

- Users:

[image: User total ram usage]

- Processes and Handle:

[image]

Comment: Windows 10 doesn't have a memory leak.  You have 32gb of memory.. are you seeing some sort of performance issue as a result of your "leak"?

Comment: I would suggest, when you know it's leaking run:
`wpr.exe -start Pool`
Leave it to leak, maybe 3 mins, then run:
`wrp.exe -stop C:\pool.etl`
Open that up in Windows Performance Analyzer (The Store version is fine)
Look at AIFO, tags and the driver responsible for the impact.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas yep, I notice a general slowness, some freeze.

Comment: @HelpingHand ty ty.
in the end I solved by reinstalling windows, now i have 4GB of ram usage after 24hours and only 80k handles